# Understanding the Android issue causing signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR) Error after a few seconds

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface, jna, android-native-library

I am running a sensor and location service, the data is passed to the TraceManager file which where it is dealt with and passed to the TraceCWrapper to be mapped to a shared C library .so , It seems the sensor and location data is fine and received in TraceManager, it then is passed into TraceCWrapper, however the app crashes after a few seconds, and the only error line i get is:

A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x8 in tid 29938 (AsyncTask #1), pid 29870 (pp.traceandroid)

```
public class TraceManager extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String TAG = "TraceManager";
    private int phoneAngle = 0;
    private double initialStepCalibrationOffset;
    private int initialPointingAngleDeg = 0;
    private int initialAlignmentMode = 0;
    private int startingFloorID = 0;
    private LatLng startingLatLong;
    private double startingAccuracy = 1.0;
    private Context context;
    private boolean isMagConsistentAtInit = false;
    private boolean isMagValid = true;
    private Timer callBackTimer;
    private String[] contentsStatic;
    private String[] contentsDynamic;
    private boolean isRunning = false;
    private TraceCWrapper traceCWrapper = new TraceCWrapper();
    Handler callbackHandler = new Handler();
    Runnable callbackRunnable;

    //internal use only
    private boolean _traceCDontActuallyUse;

    // The interval, in seconds, for providing trace updates.
    public ObservableDouble updateCallbackInterval = new ObservableDouble(0){
        @Override
        public void addOnPropertyChangedCallback(@NonNull OnPropertyChangedCallback callback) {
            if(isRunning){
                stopCallbackTimer();
                startCallbackTimer();
            }

            super.addOnPropertyChangedCallback(callback);
        }
    };

    private double updateCallBackIntervalValue = updateCallbackInterval.get();

    /// A Boolean value
    public ObservableBoolean allowsBackgroundExecution = new ObservableBoolean(false){
        @Override
        public void addOnPropertyChangedCallback(@NonNull OnPropertyChangedCallback callback) {
            if(isRunning){
                stopUpdatingTrace();
                startUpdatingTrace();
            }
            super.addOnPropertyChangedCallback(callback);
        }
    };

    private boolean allowsBackgroundExecutionValue = allowsBackgroundExecution.get();


    public TraceManager(Context context){
        this.context=context;
    }


    public TraceManager(){

    }

    public void initialiseTrace(String[] mapFloors,
                                String[] initialDynamicMaps,
                                int phoneRelativeToBodyDegree, //this comes from onboarding?
                                double updateCallBackIntervalValue,
                                boolean allowsBackgroundExecutionValue,
                                double initialStepCalibrationOffset, //standard
                                String[] iBeaconUUIDs,
                                int startingFloorID,
                                LatLng startingLatLong, //this is form the starting node
                                double startingAccuracy, //
                                boolean _traceCDontActuallyUse,
                                int phoneOrientation,
                                int phoneOrientationUse,
                                boolean magntometerValid
                                ){
        this.contentsStatic = mapFloors;
        this.contentsDynamic = initialDynamicMaps;
        this.phoneAngle = phoneRelativeToBodyDegree;
        this.initialStepCalibrationOffset = initialStepCalibrationOffset;
        this.updateCallbackInterval = updateCallbackInterval;
        this.allowsBackgroundExecution = allowsBackgroundExecution;
        this.isMagValid = magntometerValid;
        if(!(iBeaconUUIDs.length <=0)){
            LocationProvider.arrayOfUUIDsToDetect = iBeaconUUIDs;
        }else{
            Log.i(TAG, "TraceManager.init: ignoring ibeaconUIDs, because it is empty. Default used");
        };

        this.startingFloorID = startingFloorID;
        this.startingLatLong = startingLatLong;
        this.startingAccuracy = startingAccuracy;
        this.initialPointingAngleDeg = phoneOrientation;
        this.initialAlignmentMode = phoneOrientationUse;

        //internal use only
        this._traceCDontActuallyUse = _traceCDontActuallyUse;
    }

//Functions
/// Broadcast Receiver to get readings from MotionProvider/service

    public void startUpdatingSensors(){
        //Start sensor service
        Intent startService = new Intent(TraceManager.this, SensorService.class);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            startForegroundService(startService);
        } else {
            startService(startService);
        }

    }

    /// Starts the generation of trace updates.

    public void startUpdatingTrace(){
        //Start Sensors
        //startUpdatingSensors();

        //register for sensorBroadcast
        BroadcastReceiver sensorReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                Log.d(TAG, "imu Received");
                TCIMUEvent tcimuEvent = (TCIMUEvent) intent.getSerializableExtra("imu");
                traceCWrapper.provideDeviceMotion(tcimuEvent, 1, 90, RotationMode.PortraitYUp);
            }
        };
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).registerReceiver(
                sensorReceiver, new IntentFilter("imuCreated")
        );

        //register for locationBroadcast
        //register for sensorBroadcast
        BroadcastReceiver locationReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                Log.d(TAG, "location Received");
                TCLocationEvent tcLocationEvent = (TCLocationEvent) intent.getSerializableExtra("locationCreated");
                Log.d(TAG, "Inlocation reciever");
                traceCWrapper.provideLocation(tcLocationEvent);
            }
        };
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).registerReceiver(
                locationReceiver, new IntentFilter("locationCreated")
        );


        Log.d(TAG, "inside updating trace");
        //Start CallbackTimer
        startCallbackTimer();

    }

    private void CallbackUpdate() {

    /*    callbackRunnable = new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.d(TAG, "calling callback");
                traceCWrapper.getLatestTraceResult();
                callbackHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            }
        };*/
    }


    private void startCallbackTimer(){
        Log.d(TAG, "I get in here callback");
        callbackRunnable = new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.d(TAG, "calling callback");
                traceCWrapper.getLatestTraceResult();
                callbackHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            }
        };
        callbackHandler.postDelayed(callbackRunnable, 1000);
    }

    private void stopCallbackTimer(){
        callbackHandler.removeCallbacks(callbackRunnable);
    }



    //Calls TraceCWrapper upadate maps and passes the dynamic maps
/*    public void updateMaps(String[] dynamicMaps){
        traceCWrapper.updateMaps(dynamicMaps dynamicmaps){

        }
    }*/

    public void stopUpdatingTrace(){

        boolean stopSensors = true;
        if(stopSensors){
            stopUpdatingSensors();
        }

        //Callback Timer
        stopCallbackTimer();

        //State
        isRunning = false;

        //Trace terminate
        if (_traceCDontActuallyUse == false){
            traceCWrapper.terminate();
        }
    }

    private void stopUpdatingSensors() {

        //todo
        //stop the event bus
        //stop the service


    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    public void provideManualLocation(TraceManualLocation manualLocation){

        if(isRunning){
        }else{
            Log.e(TAG, "Calling provideManualLocation, but is running is set to false");
        }
        if(!_traceCDontActuallyUse){
            traceCWrapper.provideManualLocation(manualLocation);
        }
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    public void provideManualHeadingCorrection(TraceManualHeading traceManualHeading){

        if(isRunning){
        }else{
            Log.e(TAG, "Calling provideHeadingCorrection, but is running is set to false");
        }

        if (!_traceCDontActuallyUse){
            traceCWrapper.provideManualHeading(traceManualHeading);
        }

    }

    public void updateParameter(TraceCVarParameter traceCVarParameter, double value){
        if(isRunning){
        }else{
            Log.e(TAG, "Calling updateparameter, but is running is set to false");
        }
        //todo
        //callback async
    }


    //Private [START]

    boolean isInitialised = false;

    public boolean isInitialised() {
        if(!isInitialised){

        }else{
            //todo
            //send to didfinishinitialisation? confirm isMagConsistentAtInit is true
        }

        return isInitialised;
    }

    private boolean isMagConsistantAtInit = false;
    private Timer callbackTimer;


/*    public traceCallBack(int seconds){
        callBackTimer = new Timer();
        callBackTimer.schedule(new callUpdate(), seconds*1000);
    }*/

    class callUpdate extends TimerTask{

        @Override
        public void run() {
            //traceCWrapper.getLatestTraceResult();


        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_trace_manager);
    }

}
```

I do not have enough room to add the TraceCWrapper file however the library is loaded as:

```
    static CLibrary lib = Native.loadLibrary("com.waymap.app.traceandroid", CLibrary.class);
```

And as the main example the method, traceCWrapper.provideDeviceMotion() is received in TraceCWrapper as:

```
    //Provide Device Motion
    public static boolean provideDeviceMotion(TCIMUEvent mTCIMUEvent, int Status, double userHeadingDeg, float rotationMode){

        DeviceMotion dM = new DeviceMotion();
        dM.setTcimuEvent(mTCIMUEvent);
        dM.setStatus(Status);
        dM.setUserHeadingDeg(userHeadingDeg);
        dM.setRotationMode(rotationMode);
        if(isRunning) {

            new sendToTraceHandleImuEvent().execute(dM);
            isInitalized = true;
            return isInitalized;
        }else{
            Log.i(TAG, "IMU update ignored as not running");
            isInitalized = false;
            return isInitalized;
        }
    }
    public static class sendToTraceHandleImuEvent extends AsyncTask<DeviceMotion,Void,Void>{

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(DeviceMotion... devicemotions) {
            /*public class Arg extends Structure {
                public devicemotions[] var1 = new byte[9];
                public devicemotions[] var2 = new byte[5];
            }*/
            Log.d(TAG, "InTraceCwrapper Again, provideIMU");

            lib.TraceHandleImuEvent(devicemotions[0].getTcimuEvent(), devicemotions[0].getStatus(), devicemotions[0].getUserHeadingDeg(), devicemotions[0].getRotationMode());
            return null;
        }

    }
```

You will have to excuse the large amount of Logging and excess code as i have been wrestling with this for a while.

When passing my TCIMUEvent i am using the structure annotation as below:

```
@Structure.FieldOrder({ "time", "accel", "accelValid", "mag", "magValid", "gyro", "gyroValid", "pressure", "pressureValid", "temperature", "temperatureValid"})
public class TCIMUEvent extends Structure implements Serializable {

    public double time;
    public float[] accel = new float[3];
    public boolean accelValid;
    public float[] mag = new float[3];
    public boolean magValid;
    public float[] gyro = new float[3];
    public boolean gyroValid;
    public float pressure;
    public boolean pressureValid;
    public float temperature;
    public boolean temperatureValid;

    public TCIMUEvent(double time, float[] accel, boolean accelValid, float[] mag, boolean magValid, float[] gyro, boolean gyroValid, float pressure, boolean pressureValid, float temperature, boolean temperatureValid) {
        this.time = time;
        this.accel = accel;
        this.accelValid = accelValid;
        this.mag = mag;
        this.magValid = magValid;
        this.gyro = gyro;
        this.gyroValid = gyroValid;
        this.pressure = pressure;
        this.pressureValid = pressureValid;
        this.temperature = temperature;
        this.temperatureValid = temperatureValid;
    }
}
```

The Java C Mappings that are required:

```
    My Java Library to map:

    void TracehandleLocationEvent(TCLocationEvent tcLocationEvent);

    void TracehandleManualLocationEvent(TCManualLocationEvent tcManualLocationEvent);

    void TracehandleManualHeadingEvent(TCManualHeadingEvent tcManualHeadingEvent);

    void TracehandleManualInitialLocation(TCLocationEvent initialLocationEvent);

    void TraceHandleImuEvent(TCIMUEvent tcimuEvent, int Status, double userHeadingDeg, float rotationMode);

    void TraceGetResult(Double uptime, Pointer traceResult_out);

    -------- These map retrospectively to C:---------

    void TraceHandleLocationEvent (const Trace_locationSample_t *locationSample)

    void TraceHandleManualLocationEvent(const Trace_manualLocationSample_t
  *manualLocationSample)

    void TraceHandleManualHeadingEvent(const Trace_manualHeadingSample_t
  *manualHeadingSample)

     void TraceHandleLocationEvent (const Trace_locationSample_t *locationSample)

     void TraceHandleImuEvent(Trace_imuDataSample_t *imuDataSample, int *status,
  double *userHeadingDeg, StrapdownStreaming_RotationMode *currentRotateMode)

  void TraceGetResult(double time, Trace_Result_t *TraceResult)
```

The new Mappings look like this, the structures for the objects are all the same format as above in the original question:

```
    void TracehandleLocationEvent(TCLocationEvent tcLocationEvent);

    void TracehandleManualLocationEvent(TCManualLocationEvent tcManualLocationEvent);

    void TracehandleManualHeadingEvent(TCManualHeadingEvent tcManualHeadingEvent);

    void TracehandleManualInitialLocation(TCLocationEvent initialLocationEvent);

    void TraceGetResult(DoubleByReference uptime, TCResult traceResult_out);

    void TraceHandleImuEvent(TCIMUEvent tcimuEvent, IntByReference status, DoubleByReference heading, FloatByReference rotationMode);
```

The error being thrown now in relation to the empty constructors in my Structure objects:

```
java.lang.Error: Structure.getFieldOrder() on class com.dataTypes.TCLocationEvent returns names ([altitude, coordinate, horizontalAccuracy, timestamp, verticalAccuracy]) which do not match declared field names ([])
        at com.sun.jna.Structure.getFields(Structure.java:1089)
        at com.sun.jna.Structure.deriveLayout(Structure.java:1232)
        at com.sun.jna.Structure.calculateSize(Structure.java:1159)
        at com.sun.jna.Structure.calculateSize(Structure.java:1111)
        at com.sun.jna.Structure.allocateMemory(Structure.java:414)
        at com.sun.jna.Structure.<init>(Structure.java:205)
        at com.sun.jna.Structure.<init>(Structure.java:193)
        at com.sun.jna.Structure.<init>(Structure.java:180)
        at com.sun.jna.Structure.<init>(Structure.java:172)
        at com.dataTypes.TCLocationEvent.<init>(TCLocationEvent.java:30)
        at com.locationGetter.LocationService.<clinit>(LocationService.java:39)
```

Comment: Which line in your wall of code causes the error?  Would be helpful to narrow it down.  Errors like this are often failure to allocate native memory, and/or reading memory outside of allocated bounds, but it's hard to narrow down what to look at.

Comment: I know Apologies, been running round in circles this line actually contains the method that is mapped to the C library, lib.TraceHandleImuEvent(devicemotions[0].getTcimuEvent(), devicemotions[0].getStatus(), devicemotions[0].getUserHeadingDeg(), devicemotions[0].getRotationMode());

Comment: It is mapped in my Native library, then C file receives it as: void TraceHandleImuEvent(Trace_imuDataSample_t *imuDataSample, int *status,
  double *userHeadingDeg, StrapdownStreaming_RotationMode *currentRotateMode)

Comment: I don't see your mapping for the `DeviceMotion` class.

Comment: I suspect your problem is in your mappings of either `DeviceMotion` or `TCIMUevent`, neither of which you have provided.   Look for arguments that you might have mapped as promitives that are actually pointers (e.g., `int` that should be `IntByReference`) and double-check type mapping and the initialization of array sizes.

Comment: @DanielWiddis Thanks, I am completely new to JNA and am finding it a tough task, i understand i can map my TCIMUEvent by simply using the structure annotation? am i right on this? I have added the class above.

Comment: You added TCIMUevent (which looks fine) but not DeviceMotion. It would be helpful to also see (or have a link to) the native mapping for that, which may be your problem.  In particular, I have seen online that the `Status` field is referred to as a pointer (`int *status`) but your function mapping uses a plain `int`.  Without seeing the source or your mapping, however, I can't tell you.

Comment: @DanielWiddis I can see you have a lot of experience, I have added the mappings i would be really grateful if you can help me in anyway as i am struggling. Thanks.

Comment: experience = I've hit these errors before. :)   This looks problematic: `void TraceHandleImuEvent(TCIMUEvent tcimuEvent, int Status, double userHeadingDeg, float rotationMode);` (note `int` and `double` and `float` primitives) vs. the native mapping showing pointers: `void TraceHandleImuEvent(Trace_imuDataSample_t *imuDataSample, int *status,
  double *userHeadingDeg, StrapdownStreaming_RotationMode *currentRotateMode)`.  So you're passing an int where native expects a poniter, and it's going to the memory location of your raw int and causing the crash.

Comment: @DanielWiddis OK thanks, so does it look like i am using the structure correctly, to represent the objects i need to pass, so i need to look at passing my primitives as pointers, And i will look into that now, but it's the IntByReference you mentioned earlier, so i am passing a reference as appose to the value. but i don't need to use the 'Pointer' - com.sun.jna.Pointer? Sorry to take up your time i need to map these before tomorrow!

Comment: No, the "ByReference" mappings are the pointers. You use `getValue()` to extract the primitives.

Comment: @DanielWiddis Really appreciate your help on this, so i have altered the mapping to what i think looks OK i have added them to the question if you want to see i would really appreciate it. The issue is i now have an error the classes where i use the structure annotation to allow me to pass as struct it has an issue with my empty constructor, however i need this to allow me to work with the objects? how do i overcome this, is this usual? the error is as i have added to the end of the question for you, thanks Daniel.

Comment: @DanielWiddis It look like that error was just because the variable were private and not public, However i am still getting the original error: A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x8 in tid 5952 (AsyncTask #1), pid 5923 (pp.traceandroid) Am i doing a lot more wrong? Or not doing something? is my implementation of Structure correct? thank you again apologies as i am under a little pressure to get this done, otherwise i would ask for so much guidance.

Comment: Also if you do get chance to look at this, I am also having an issue maybe you have experience of, i have to pass a String[] contentsStatic, in the JNA documentation i see it maps to Char**, however the C code is generated form MatLab so the C side is wanting a 'const emxArray_char_T *contentsStatic'. Thanks if you get chance Daniel @DanielWiddis

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SIGSEGV errors with JNA mappings are frequently caused by accessing native memory you don't own.  Problems vary, but the first place to look is your structure type mappings and method/function argument mappings.

As one specific example (there may be more), your code includes this mapping:

```
void TraceHandleImuEvent(TCIMUEvent tcimuEvent, int Status,
    double userHeadingDeg, float rotationMode);
```

However, the native mapping does not expect an `int`, `double`, and `float` here. It expects pointers:

```
void TraceHandleImuEvent(Trace_imuDataSample_t *imuDataSample, int *status,
    double *userHeadingDeg, StrapdownStreaming_RotationMode *currentRotateMode)
```

(Structures like `TCIMUEvent` are automatically mapped to their pointers when passed as arguments, so that one's okay.)

What is happening is that you are passing an `int` for status (e.g., 8) but the native code is thinking "There's an integer stored at memory location `0x8`."  You don't own that memory, and thus the error.

`IntByReference` would be the correct type mapping here, and for many of those function arguments.

Comment: I get the same error, but only when I use the built-in profiler in Android Studio. Now, I wonder, does the profiler cause that error, or does it simply bring the error out in the open (pardon my English, it's not my native tongue). Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: @DannyE.K.vanderKolk as I began my comment, there's an error accessing native memory that you don't own somewhere. Each problem is different. It's unlikely to be a profiler.  Ask a new question and post your code and what you've tried.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply, Daniel. It would be too much effort to post my code, since I don't know where the error occurs, and I just can't post 9000+ lines of code. I'm still confused since the error never occurs when I just use my app (even for a long time). Guess it's time for some thorough debugging :) Have a nice day!